# cvSetImageROI versus cv::Mat(cv::Rect())

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm porting some code from the old C interface to the new C++ interface, and I have a slight issue. Given the code for greyscale image processing:

```
const int MARGIN = 5;
IplImage image = ....;
cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(MARGIN, 0, image.width - MARGIN, image.height));
for (int y = MARGIN; y < image.height - MARGIN; y++)
{
    uchar ptr = (uchar *) image.imageData + y * image.widthStep + MARGIN;
    for (int x = MARGIN; x < image.width - MARGIN; x++, ptr++)
    {
        // ...code referencing *ptr only
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

Translating to the C++ interface, I use this:

```
cv::Mat image = ....;
cv::Mat roiImage = image(cv::Rect(MARGIN, 0, image.cols - MARGIN, image.rows));
for (int y = MARGIN; y < roiImage.rows - MARGIN; y++)
{
    uchar ptr = roiImage.ptr<uchar>(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < roiImage.cols; x++, ptr++)
    {
        // ...code referencing *ptr only
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

This gives me basically the same result as before.

However, the existing code tries to access `ptr[-1]` and `ptr[+1]`, which is into the margins the first and last time round the inner loop. Is `roiImage.ptr<uchar>(y)[-1]` safe in this example, or should I be using `image` as is without slicing out the ROI as I'll be accessing `image.ptr<uchar>(y)[MARGIN-1]`?

Comment: I guess you are aware that MARGIN does not represent the Y axis, if in case you have mistakenly assumed.

Comment: Note I've fixed a couple of issues in my post, including using `image.cols` instead of `roiImage.cols` in the inner loop. I'm not sure I quite get your comment, but I am aware/of the understanding that both `cv::Rect` and `cvRect` use `x`, `y`, `w`, `h` order. Also the original code is, shall we say, not so expert in its use of OpenCV. Xmas cheer prevents me adding "..or of pretty much anything, to be frank."

Comment: Having slept on the problem, I think `roiImage` is unnecessary, but I'm still unclear as to whether `image.imageData` is guaranteed to be the same value regardless of whether or not an ROI has been set. Note I have just found [this page](http://study.marearts.com/2013/02/the-thing-be-careful-when-you-use.html), which if it is correct, answers my questions, so if someone wants to make an answer out of it...